# autocommand for filetypes working for setting options but not for mappings

Tags: vim

I have the following lines in my [vimrc](/questions/tagged/vimrc):

```
set shiftwidth=4
autocmd FileType tex setlocal shiftwidth=2
autocmd FileType tex map xyz doSomething
```

If I open a, say, text file (filetype is set correctly), and do `set sw`, I get 4.
If I open a tex file (filetype is set correctly), I get 2 for `set sw`. That part works!

Now for the mapping I type `map xyz`, and I see that the mapping is done for both filetypes. What am I doing wrong?

At first I thought something with the mapping is wrong, so I tried:

```
set history=100
autocmd FileType tex setlocal history=123
```

But history is set to 123 for all filetypes... How can `shiftwidth` work, but `history` not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What `:setlocal` is to `:set`, `:map <buffer>` is to `:map` (see `:h :map-local`):

```
autocmd FileType tex map <buffer> xyz doSomething
```

Also, [you should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.

And I would recommend putting the settings and mappings into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim` instead of defining lots of `:autocmd FileType`; this requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`.

#### Option scopes

The `:help` offers hints which options are global only (like `'history'`), and which support (either *buffer* or *window*)-local values; compare the second line:

```
'history' 'hi'      number  (Vim default: 20, Vi default: 0)
                    global
'shiftwidth' 'sw'   number  (default 8)
                    local to buffer
```

Comment: Thanks, very clear answer and exactly what I was looking for. It doesn't answer, though, why `setlocal history` does not work. Is that some sort of a global setting that cannot be changed locally? It's not important since I don't want to do that, just curious. :-)

Comment: I somehow missed that part... I've appended an explanation for that, too!