# How do I set a .vimrc configuration for many file types?

Tags: vim

Let's say I want one group of settings for HTML, CSS and JavaScript files but another set for Ruby files (completely different). What's the simplest way to do this?

Comment: This answer might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21407298/1945981

Comment: Just looking at the "Related" questions on this page, I see this one that asks the same question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171184/how-to-set-a-different-colorscheme-for-each-file-type-in-vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `ftplugin` directory with filetype-specific settings inside
`.vim` directory

```
.vim
└── ftplugin
    └── ruby.vim
    └── markdown.vim
```

And keep your settings there. The are applied when file with
corresponding filetype is opened.

Also, you might need to have filetype detection(if not detected
properly). You can put this to your `.vimrc`

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.markdown,*.md,*.mdown,*.mkd,*.mkdn set ft=markdown
```

Or, put it into `ftdetect` directory

```
.vim
└── ftdetect
    └── markdown.vim
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give global settings like this.

For other files:

```
set shiftwidth=4
```

for Ruby files:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.rb set shiftwidth=2
```

You can get what you want via `autocmd`, it's format as follows:

```
au[tocmd] [group] {event} {pattern} [nested] {cmd}
```

`[group]` and `[nested]` are optional.As I give the example above, `BufRead,BufNewFile` is the event, `*.rb` is the pattern, and `set shiftwidth=2` is the cmd.

more information about `autocmd`, please refer: `:help automcd`

Comment: Thanks! What if I want to add many settings to a file type do I have to write `autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.filename` each time? Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Then you can try to write a filetype plugin.And config it in the new plugin.